# How to view the display figures from different directory based on mentioned in href attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using this xml tag to display figures.

```
<figure xml:id="ecog473-fig-0001">
    <mediaResourceGroup>
        <mediaResource alt="image" href="urn:x-wiley:09067590:media:ecog473:ecog473-fig-0001"/>
        <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_n/ecog473-fig-0001.png" rendition="webOriginal"/>
        <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/gif" href="image_t/ecog473-fig-0001-t.gif" rendition="webLoRes"/>
        <mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_m/ecog473-fig-0001-m.png" rendition="webHiRes"/>
    </mediaResourceGroup>
    <caption>
        <p>....</p>
    </caption>
</figure>
```

**In XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="//figure">
    <p><a name="{@xml:id}"/>
        <table class="table" width="90%" align="center">
            <tr><td align="center"><img src="{@href}" alt="{@href}"/><xsl:apply-templates select="mediaResource"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="justify"><b><xsl:apply-templates select="label"/></b><xsl:apply-templates select="caption"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mediaResource">
    <img src=".\image_n\*.png" title="{@href}" alt="{@href}" width="500"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But captions only viewing in browser, even figures are presenting in the `image_{n|m|t}` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your template matches the `figure` context. In that context, there is no `@href` attribute or `mediaResource` *child*.

In the `img` that is inside the `figure` template you are actually selecting `<img src="/figure/@href" alt="/figure/@href">`, and in the `xsl:apply-templates` you are actually using `<xsl:apply-templates select="/figure/mediaResource"/>` - none of these paths exist in your example.

To apply your templates correctly, according to your source example you have to use `mediaResourceGroup/mediaResource`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mediaResourceGroup/mediaResource"/>
```

That will call your `mediaResource` template and print your images.

The caption works because `caption` is actually a *child* of `figure`.

It seems that the `<img>` in the `figure` template is misplaced (unless there actually *is* an `img` which is a direct child o `figure`, not shown in your code).

**EDIT**: to display *only* the images that start with `image_n` you can use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="mediaResource[starts-with(@href, 'image_n')]">
    <img src="{@href}" title="{@href}" alt="{@href}" width="500"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It uses an XPath *predicate* to filter the match results to only the `mediaResource` nodes that have an `href` attribute that starts with the string `image_n`. If you actually want that URL in the `src` attribute (to show the image), then you should use it there. *If* you need to adjust the URL to a different relative position, you can do so outside the curly braces, for example:

```
<img src="../other-folder/images/{@href}" />
```

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha. 3 image's file name only viewing, but not displayed.however just i want display the figures which is in the folder **"image_n"**. don't need to display 3 figures.